# How to make HTML5 contenteditable div allowing only text in firefox?

Tags: html, contenteditable

I want to make div with contentEditable attribute which is allowing only text. It's easily achievable in Chrome by using:

```
<div contenteditable="plaintext-only"></div>
```

However it doesn't work in Firefox. Is there a way how to make text-only contenteditable div in Firefox ? I know it is possible, because Google Plus has such div, but I don't know how they do it.

Comment: There is a strange way: listen for "beforeinput" event (it is behind a flag in current Firefox version, so you may polyfill it by listening for "drop", "paste", "keydown" event), prevent the default action based on InputEvent#inputType, modify the data to contain only plain text for insertion events and use `document.execCommand('insetText', false, data)`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sadly, you can’t. As this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10672378/564721) points out the [spec](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/interaction.html#contenteditable) only specifies `true`, `false` and `inherit` as valid parameters. The subject seems to have been [discussed](https://www.w3.org/Bugs/Public/show_bug.cgi?id=14554) but if I’m not mistaken only Webkit implements support for `plaintext-only`.

Answer (score 11):

I ran into this problem myself. Here is my solution which I have tested in Firefox and Chrome:

Ensure the `contenteditable` div has the css `white-space: pre`, `pre-line` or `pre-wrap` so that it displays `\n` as new lines.

Override the "enter" key so that when we are typing, it does not create any `<div>` or `<br>` tags

```js
myDiv.addEventListener("keydown", e => {
    //override pressing enter in contenteditable
    if (e.keyCode == 13)
    {
        //don't automatically put in divs
        e.preventDefault();
        e.stopPropagation();
        //insert newline
        insertTextAtSelection(myDiv, "\n");
    }
});
```

Secondly, override the paste event to only ever fetch the plaintext

```js
//override paste
myDiv.addEventListener("paste", e => {
    //cancel paste
    e.preventDefault();
    //get plaintext from clipboard
    let text = (e.originalEvent || e).clipboardData.getData('text/plain');
    //insert text manually
    insertTextAtSelection(myDiv, text);
});
```

And here is the supporting function which inserts text into the textContent of a div, and returns the cursor to the proper position afterwards.

```js
function insertTextAtSelection(div, txt) {
    //get selection area so we can position insert
    let sel = window.getSelection();
    let text = div.textContent;
    let before = Math.min(sel.focusOffset, sel.anchorOffset);
    let after = Math.max(sel.focusOffset, sel.anchorOffset);
    //ensure string ends with \n so it displays properly
    let afterStr = text.substring(after);
    if (afterStr == "") afterStr = "\n";
    //insert content
    div.textContent = text.substring(0, before) + txt + afterStr;
    //restore cursor at correct position
    sel.removeAllRanges();
    let range = document.createRange();
    //childNodes[0] should be all the text
    range.setStart(div.childNodes[0], before + txt.length);
    range.setEnd(div.childNodes[0], before + txt.length);
    sel.addRange(range);
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/1te5hwv0/